# Django admin with multiple heritage

Tags: django, admin, models, multiple-inheritance

I have the following class

```
class master(models.Model):
    topic = models.ManyToManyField('Topic')

class child1(master):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class child2(master):
    answer_display = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
```

In the django admin, I wish add an object child1 and at the same time an object child2 that have the same ID given by the parrent model.

How I'm supposed to do that ?

Edit:
If I create an object child1 and an object child2, i don't have the same master ID as i wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a good way to organised my models

I change It for something like that

```
class master(models.Model):
    topic = models.ManyToManyField('Topic')

class child1(child2):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class child2(master):
    answer_display = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you want, but if you want to link the 2 "childs" to a "parent", you could create a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) field on both of the childs and use that to link to a "parent" model.

Also if you want your child1 and child2 models to inherit from the `master` model, it must have `abstract = True` in its `class Meta`.

```
class master(models.Model):
    topic = models.ManyToManyField('Topic')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class child1(master):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
```

Comment: I don't want change my current model, it's works.
But I wish add contents with the django admin, ans i don't understand how i'm supposed to write my admin.py
Because i wish add content to both child in the same time